# detect if the arrow button from QScrollBar is pressed

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractslider

Is there a signal that I can emit if the arrow button of the `QScrollBar` is pressed? As far as I know there is only the `sliderPressed()` signal. I want, if it exists, another solution from `valueChanged()` signal.

Comment: You want to emit or **connect to**? Because if you are emitting, means your coding your widget ie, you can creat your own signal...

Comment: For what reason good sir?, I can't think of a reason you would need to know if a specific arrow is pressed on a slider.

Comment: I have implemented a grid that fetches the data from a database. When i press the arrow key i want to get the new data silmuntaneously. But when i scoll or move the slider i don't want the to get the new data until the slider is stopped. So i can't use the valueChanged() singal because this affect also the movement of the slider.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it connecting the same callback function to `sliderReleased()` and `valueChanged()` and checking in the function if the slider is "down" (meaning pushed) with `isSliderDown()`:

```
    slider = QtGui.QScrollBar()
    slider.valueChanged.connect(slider_callback)
    slider.sliderReleased.connect(slider_callback)

    def slider_callback():
       if slider.isSliderDown():
          pass
       else:
          print("now i am updating")
```

Answer (score 0):

All signals QScrollBar emits (inherited from [QAbstractSlider](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#signals)) related o slider/value changed:

```
void    actionTriggered ( int action )
void    rangeChanged ( int min, int max )
void    sliderMoved ( int value )
void    sliderPressed ()
void    sliderReleased ()
void    valueChanged ( int value )
```